# Appending an xml-node which is read from file breaks pretty_print for adjacent nodes

Tags: python, xml, append, elementtree, pretty-print

I'm generating a XML-file with python's etree library. One node in the generated file is read from an existing XML-file. Adding this element breaks the pretty_print for the nodes directly before and after.

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
from lxml import etree

root = etree.Element("startNode")
subnode1 = etree.SubElement(root, "SubNode1")
subnode1Child1 = etree.SubElement(subnode1, "subNode1Child1")
etree.SubElement(subnode1Child1, "Child1")
etree.SubElement(subnode1Child1, "Child2")

f = open('/xml_testdata/ext_file.xml','r')
ext_xml = etree.fromstring(f.read())
ext_subnode = ext_xml.find("ExtNode")
subnode1.append(ext_subnode)

subnode1Child2 = etree.SubElement(subnode1, "subNode1Child2")
etree.SubElement(subnode1Child2, "Child1")
etree.SubElement(subnode1Child2, "Child2")

tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("testfile.xml", xml_declaration=True, pretty_print=True)
```

which gives this result:

```xml
<startNode>
    <SubNode1><subNode1Child1><Child1/><Child2/></subNode1Child1><ExtNode>
            <NodeFromExt>
                <SubNodeFromExt1/>
            </NodeFromExt>
            <NodeFromExt>
                <SubNodeFromExt2/>
                <AnotherSubNodeFromExt2>
                    <SubSubNode/>
                    <AllPrettyHere>
                        <Child/>
                    </AllPrettyHere>
                </AnotherSubNodeFromExt2>
            </NodeFromExt>
    </ExtNode>
    <subNode1Child2><Child1/><Child2/></subNode1Child2></SubNode1>
</startNode>
```

Not very readable, is it? Even worse when "subNodeChild" contains a lot more subnodes than this example!

Without appending the external elements, it looks like this:

```xml
<startNode>
  <SubNode1>
    <subNode1Child1>
      <Child1/>
      <Child2/>
    </subNode1Child1>
    <subNode1Child2>
      <Child1/>
      <Child2/>
    </subNode1Child2>
  </SubNode1>
</startNode>
```

So the problem is caused by appending the external elements!

Is there a way to append the external elements without breaking the pretty_print-output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get nicer pretty-printed output by using a parser object that removes ignorable whitespace when parsing the existing XML file.

Instead of this:

```
f = open('/xml_testdata/ext_file.xml','r')
ext_xml = etree.fromstring(f.read())
```

Use this:

```
f = open('/xml_testdata/ext_file.xml', 'r')
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
ext_xml = etree.fromstring(f.read(), parser)
```

See also:

- http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html
- http://lxml.de/FAQ.html#why-doesn-t-the-pretty-print-option-reformat-my-xml-output

Comment: By the way, it is possible to use `etree.parse('/xml_testdata/ext_file.xml', parser)` instead of `etree.fromstring(f.read(), parser)`.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to somewhat mitigate the effect by creating "ExtNode" with etree.SubElement and appending the elements inside it:

```py
ext_node = etree.SubElement(subnode1, "ExtNode")
for element in ext_xml.findall("ExtNode/NodeFromExt")
  ext_node.append(element)
```

which has this result:

```xml
<startNode>
  <SubNode1>
    <subNode1Child1>
      <Child1/>
      <Child2/>
    </subNode1Child1>
    <ExtNode><NodeFromExt>
      <SubNodeFromExt1/>
        </NodeFromExt>
    <NodeFromExt>
      <SubNodeFromExt2/>
        <AnotherSubNodeFromExt2>
          <SubSubNode/>
          <AllPrettyHere>
            <Child/>
          </AllPrettyHere>
        </AnotherSubNodeFromExt2>
    </NodeFromExt>
  </ExtNode>
    <subNode1Child2>
      <Child1/>
      <Child2/>
    </subNode1Child2>
  </SubNode1>
</startNode>
```

Not perfect, but at least human readable (Which is the whole point of pretty_print, right?)

To satisfy my OCD, I'd still be interested if there is a way to get a flawlessly formatted file!